# Error while opening sharepoint list in datasheetview and exporting to excel

Tags: list, administration, excel, excel-services

I have a List which is having around 14000 items in it.while opening that list in datasheet view it is giving error .

Below is a summary of the issue:

After selecting datasheet view :

```
"Cannot connect to the server at this time.  You can continue working with this list, but some data may not be available."

 "Unable to retrieve all data."(At the bottom of data sheet view)
```

The item counts displays say 100 out of 14000 items.

Exporting List to excel is giving only 2000 records out of 14000 records.

Other Observations   -

This is happening to only one list on the site .There are other lists in the site whose no. of records is equal to 8000 to 9000.They are working absolutely fine without any error.

Also, If I am saving this list as a template and creating another list with it ,then it is working absolutely fine with 14000 records,so the issue does not seem to be related with no. of records as the template list is working fine.

I have checked the Alternate access mapping setting ,its fine.

It should not be related to lookup or date field or any other column as the list created from it template is working fine with all these columns.

I checked below links also ,but doesn't seem to work in my case.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/974b9168-f548-409b-a7f9-a79b9fdd4c50/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/87077dd8-a329-48e8-b42d-d0a8bf87b082

Answer (score 2):

What your seeing are the default limits put in place by SharePoint for performance reasons.

A list of the limits can be found in this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx)

If you want to change the limits [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold.aspx) has an example of how to do that though it may cause performance problems on your farm. I would not change any of the limits without first trying it on a test farm and doing load testing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but as i mentioned earlier the problem does not seem to be occuring because of the no. of records because the list created from its template have the same no. of records(i.e 14000+) and it is working absolutely fine without any error and problem in exporting.So,the problem seems to be only with one particular list .